# How to ship an order using cash on delivery in spree commerce?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

In spree commerce is there any way to ship an order without the payment.

Comment: hi, you want to skip the payment method ?

Comment: Yes i was trying it for cash on delivery so that the item can be shipped from without approving the payments .

Answer (score 1):

if you want to skip payment method for that you have to create order_decorator.rb file in models and write these lines of code.

```
Spree::Order.class_eval do
 remove_checkout_step :payment  
end
```